# Converting listview -> listview.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I tried to change `listview` to `listview.builder` but I did not succeed.

Here is my code:

```
class UserInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: users.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(document.data()['full_name']),
                subtitle: new Text(document.data()['company']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please tell us what error you face

Comment: No error I just want to add some effects, from Opacity() widget but i can't manage how to do

Answer (score 0):

Based from your code:

```dart
class UserInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: users.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder:(context, index){
               return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['full_name']),
                subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['company']),
               );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```